# Including a library or contribution into qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

I try to use the xqjqplot library within qooxdoo, but i still get a error message during generating with generate-source.

Error:

```
Unknown global symbol referenced: qxjqplot.Plot
```

My config.json looks like

```
"libraries" : {
   "library" : [{
     "manifest"   : "contrib://qxjqplot/trunk/Manifest.json",
     "uri"        : "../QxJqPlot/trunk" // the trunk of the checked out QX lib
   }]
},
```

In my class i try to access qxjqplot with `var plot = new qxjqplot.Plot( .... );` but the namespace is not resolved.

I Use QX 1.0.2-pre. Are there any additinal adjustments required

What do i have to do to get this working?

******* *edit* ***********

After migrating to 1.2.1 i get the same errors. The library is linked correctly and the compiler does not throw the Error (described above) anymore. Usualy this should work, but it doesnt. During Initializing the Plot the namespace is not found.

******* *end edit* *******

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settng the URI with a absolute path did work. Perhaps this was an browser-dependent issue.

Answer (score 1):

For one, why are you using a -pre version, when 1.0.2 is since long released?!

Then, unless you are 100% sure you know what you're doing, I would recommend dropping the "uri" parameter from the library entry. This can only work if you run the app from a web server (which is not recommended for source versions anyway). Are you sure this URI resolves to the correct path during run time? The default URI construction of the generator is usually fine and does what you want. If you can run your app from a `file://` URL, you should rely on that.

Is the contrib downloaded correctly? Do you get warnings when the generator tries to access it online? There were issues with Sourceforge changing their ViewVC frontend (see this [bug](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3769) for a patch for this).

Can you check your download cache?! On Linux it's usually under /tmp/cache/downloads (You can use `generate.py source -w` to get a verbose logging of your job settings; scan for `'cache': {...'downloads':...}` under the heading `>>> Expanded job config:` to find the path on your file system).

If you are in doubt if the contrib is downloaded correctly, download it from Sourceforge [directly](http://qooxdoo-contrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/qooxdoo-contrib/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/QxJqPlot/trunk/) (look for "Download GNU tarball"). Put it in a suitable path on your file system and just adapt the "manifest" parameter of the library entry to point to the local Manifest.json (relative paths work best).

What do you get?